# Build dict through for loop without repetition

Tags: python, django

My code is currently very repetitive with `grouped_events.setdefault('VAR', []).append(event)` and `event_data_by_organizer[organizer.pk]['events_draft'] = grouped_events.get('VAR')`. Do you see any better way in writing this?

Currently, my best idea would be to write a function above where I insert the strings such as 'archived' etc.

```
   # Events by status
    grouped_events = {}
    for event in events:
        if event.status == EventStatus.ARCHIVED:
            grouped_events.setdefault('archived', []).append(event)
        elif event.status == EventStatus.DRAFT:
            grouped_events.setdefault('draft', []).append(event)
        elif event.is_over:
            grouped_events.setdefault('past', []).append(event)
        else:
            grouped_events.setdefault('live', []).append(event)

    event_data_by_organizer[organizer.pk][
        'events_archived'
    ] = grouped_events.get('archived')
    event_data_by_organizer[organizer.pk]['events_draft'] = grouped_events.get(
        'draft'
    )
    event_data_by_organizer[organizer.pk]['events_past'] = grouped_events.get(
        'past'
    )
    event_data_by_organizer[organizer.pk]['events_live'] = grouped_events.get(
        'live'
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` instead of manually calling `setdefault`.
A helper mapping (`EVENT_MAPPING`) can be used to reduce code for `event_data_by_organizer` assignment.

Due to conditions on which you group events, it's difficult to further shorten `group_events(events)` (or at least I don't see a way).

```
from collections import defaultdict


EVENT_MAPPING = {
    "archived": "events_archived",
    "draft": "events_draft",
    "past": "events_past",
    "live": "events_live",
}


def group_events(events):
    grouped_events = defaultdict(list)

    for event in events:
        if event.status == EventStatus.ARCHIVED:
            events = grouped_events["archived"]
        elif event.status == EventStatus.DRAFT:
            events = grouped_events["draft"]
        elif event.is_over:
            events = grouped_events["past"]
        else:
            events = grouped_events["live"]

        events.append(event)

    return grouped_events


def set_organizer_events(events_by_organizer, organizer_pk, grouped_events):
    for event, state in EVENT_MAPPING.items():
        events_by_organizer[organizer_pk][state] = grouped_events[event]


my_grouped_events = group_events(my_events)
set_organizer_events(my_organizers, 1, my_grouped_events)
```